Understanding DC solenoid inrush current (oscilloscope readings)
ORIGINAL:
I'm struggling to understand the behaviour of my system, and would appreciate some advice.
I have a 'scope with a current probe. I've included two images of these (both current profiles. 100mV = 1A.)
I'm testing a very small air core solenoid, designed to be pulsed. When I activate it, the current initially overshoots the expected value (from Ohm's law.) I know this is inrush current, but I'm really struggling to understand why it has a near instantaneous overshoot, then slowly ramps down (nearly) linearly. I'm using a DC power supply (which I believe is voltage controlled.) I set the voltage to be lower than what it should be to ensure that there is no overvoltage.
I use the same circuitry (signal generator + transistor) on a purely resistive load (matching the solenoid's resistance.) This setup behaves exactly as expected - a perfectly square pulse (see images.) The voltage and current are identical.
Can someone please explain the shape of the solenoid's current profile, where it instantly overshoots, then (almost) linearly ramps down?
Everything that I have read about inrush/inductors suggests that the overshoot should happen non-instantaneously.
If anyone has any advice, I'd really appreciate it!
Just FYI, the solenoid diameter is 2 mm, length 7mm, N = 86, wire D = 70 microns, current was 1A, voltage for the image was set to 4.9 V, solenoid resistance = 4.09 ohms.
UPDATE1: Wow, massive thanks everyone for detailed replies! I've added an image of the whole setup. I intend to add a ferromagnetic actuator, but currently (including these current profiles) it is purely an air core solenoid. I've used two different current probes, I get the same readings. The transistor is a TIP31C (sorry, should have said!). I never considered the temperature aspect - the solenoid structure is a brass pipe (chosen for thermal conductivity) - not sure if that makes a difference with the time scales involved though! I agree that the ramp down and temp makes a lot of sense! My main worry is the quite significant initial current overshoot, which is quite baffling!
I've also added two images of a 3A test (rather than 1A) - the same ramping effect occurs, but at a sharper degree. The first image is 20 V, the second is 14V. Much sharper ramp down on the higher voltage. I significantly zoomed in on these ones (Also a shorter pulse due to higher current). There is 2.02 Ohms of resistance in the whole system without the solenoid. Any further details please let me know!
UPDATE2: Massive thank you everyone - I am in complete agreement that the ramping down is due to temperature coefficients (this explains the sharper ramping with the higher current tests).
Unfortunately I'm still struggling to understand why there is a massive overshoot (specifically in the 20V, 3A test). I have a 4 Ohm solenoid, and I measured the rest of the circuit to be 2 Ohms. So I'm not sure how the current reaches 4.5 A in the 20 V test. I have a hypothesis: perhaps the 2 Ohm system (everything except solenoid) resistance was an overestimate, based on the transistor having a lower resistance when there is 3A current flowing through it? I can't remember the current I sent through the transistor when measuring total resistance, but it would have been less than 3A!






What are the characteristics of your solenoid? What's its inductance, mostly; the numbers you've given suggest its inductance would be way too small to have any influence at the time scale you're looking at.

What probe did you use? What bandwidth does it have? An image of the test would be good.

Keep in mind that practical inductors have capacitance between turns

Just edit the question if you have more information, what you did now by adding a wall of text before the question made it impossible for at least me to understand. Maybe doesn't matter what I understand or not, but it helps to be clear if you want more people to take the time to help.

Good idea, have updated. Thank you!

I don't see any overshoot in the curves. Wire resistance increasing due to heating explains the slanted top. Besides that, what I believe is happening is simply that the circuit does not behave the way you think it does, thus you don't get the current you want. While a MOSFET that is turned on hard behaves as a resistor, a bipolar definitely does not. Also we have no idea if the transistor is saturated or not. So if you do the math expecting a fixed resistance value, it will be wrong.

Inductors do not exhibit any inrush current on their own. The inrush current associated with solenoids and motors is due to the interaction of the inductor with a mechanical system; as the mechanical parts start moving, the back EMF thus generated reduces the current through the device. For solenoids in particular, once the mechanical parts reach the end and stop moving, the current returns to the initial high value unless an economizer is used. This is why you don't typically talk about inrush current in the context of a relay coil, for instance.
You do not mention any mechanical parts in your system, so I'm left to assume it must be just an air-core inductor, not a solenoid being used to actuate a piston. As such, no inrush current is to be expected. The inductance of your coil can be estimated from the numbers given as about 3.7 μH, which in conjunction with your 4.09 Ω resistance, gives a time constant of about 900 ns, so you'd expect the current in the inductor to reach its final value by about 5 μs after turning it on. It looks like your scope is set to a timebase of 100 ms per division, which is far too long to see any impact from the inductance whatsoever. You'll want to zoom in by a lot.

Massive thanks for your detailed reply! Yeah, I also did some maths with time constants and very quickly ruled that out! Do you know what could be causing this initial overshoot, if not inrush current? It's really significant and considering it doesn't occur on the resistor dummy load, I assumed it had to be inductance related? The temperature aspect (from other replies) makes a lot of sense, but not sure why there is such an initial overshoot?

@JP12321 What you see there does look to me like it's a thermal thing.

100%, thank you! I added a new hypothesis to the original question regarding overshoot, I think that might be it?

@JP12321 How did you measure the circuit resistance, and what type of transistor are you using? The resistance of a transistor is only a meaningful measurement for certain types, primarily MOSFETs and JFETs. If you're using a BJT or IGBT, the 2 Ω figure you state is completely meaningless.

This was the total resistance, including leads (they're quite long to be fair!), breadboard etc. The only way I could think of measuring all of this was by replacing the solenoid with my benchtop multimeter - I measured current then used Ohm's Law to work out resistance (voltage read from the power supply). This was steady state, i.e. a lower current and not pulsed. Looking back, is there perhaps a better way of measuring it all? Thanks again for your help!

Oh sorry, forgot to say TIP31C (pretty sure it's a BJT...)

@JP12321 "resistance" of a BJT is meaningless, as a BJT in the on state is highly nonlinear.

Resistivity of copper has a positive temperature coefficient, meaning it increases resistance with temperature.
It's possible that your coil is heating up slightly, increasing resistance, and thus decreasing current for a given voltage drive.
Try dunking it in ice water (if you're working with safe, low voltages < 15V or so) or blowing a strong fan over it and see if the behavior changes.
The resistor, on the other hand, is designed with lower temperature coefficient, something like +/- 100-200 ppm/K is pretty standard, whereas copper is closer to +3900 ppm/K (0.39 %/K).
You could try a current-driver instead of voltage driver if you want to overcome this effect but still have the same magnetic force.

Many thanks - that would make a lot of sense! I'm struggling to understand why there is an initial overshoot though? In my 20V 3A test (new images), I initially get ~4.5 A - this then drops down. I had to reduce pulse duration as the solenoid smoked slightly! But on an earlier test with longer duration, the current would ramp down to the expected 3A!

"solenoid smoked" = it's getting hot.  not sure what temperature enamel will smoke but probably > couple hundred C.       the coil starts at room temp (25C) and has a resistance of 4.1 ohms (your data). Assuming you give it 4.1V for 1.0A.   It quickly heats to 150C (my guess), meaning it has +125C rise. at .39% / C  that is approx +50% increase in resistance, so now it's ~6.1 ohms.  the same 4.1V you are driving with now results in 0.67A.

like i said, get a strong blower fan or dunk it in cold water.  you will notice the slope of your decreasing current will decrease, because it won't heat up as quickly with the water / moving-air to cool it.

@Hearth, valuable edit, thank you.

@JP12321, sorry forgot to tag you. additional comment now that i see your 3A test. the reason it is happening with a steeper slope is because at 3A the solenoid is now heating up 9x as fast as it did in the 1A test.   It would be losing heat more quickly too, so not exactly 9x faster, but the results make sense for my hypothesis.

Yeah am in 100% agreement, thank you so much!

The slow current decrease could be due to the coil heating up. It seems tiny and is dissipating about 5W so it'll heat up very fast, and copper resistivity has a positive tempco.
I'd like to see more details on the overshoot. I can think of the following suspects:

It is switched with a MOSFET, and the current sense resistor is in the source wire

Then the sense resistor will also measure the MOSFET's turn-on gate current, which will cause a turn-on positive spike and a turn-off negative spike.

Magnetic crosstalk between the coil and measurement setup

VCC transient response


If you use a MOSFET to switch the coil on/off, then current flowing through it will depend on coil resistance and supply voltage. There is no such thing as a constant voltage supply, it always has some impedance. So it could be that what you are seeing is simply the power supply's transient response to a load current step, especially if long wires are involved. You can investigate by probing the supply voltage at the point of load.

Amazing, thank you! I'll be in the lab later today, good shout with the voltage probes too! I'm using a TIP31C, which I believe is a BJT. Will this cause similar symptoms? I forgot to add, but I use a flyback diode to prevent kickback!

Probably less base current spike with a BJT. It's hard to say because the turn-on spike is just 1 pixel on the scope shot!

I added a new Hypothesis to the question, perhaps this is the cause of the overshoot? Sorry, I should have captured just the spike, unfortunately have left the lab for today!

Ramp down is definitely resistivity change due to temperature in wire - overshoot is due to the BJT having varying resistance.
